# SQL notification problems upon Change from local IIS to azure APP

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure

I am trying to upgrade my application from being in a local machine (both application and SQL server) to using the combination of Azure APP and Azure SQL service. I have successfully published the code in the Azure Web App, and the Application works except from one error that keeps on comming. 
"{serviceResponse:{success:false,message:"System.InvalidOperationException: When using SqlDependency without providing an options value, SqlDependency.Start() must be called prior to execution of a command added to the SqlDependency instance."

in the Application start I am indeed using the SqlDependency that works only locally. The only sort of solution I found is to use the SqlNotificationRequest, but I have not been able to make it work using it.

What corrections do I need to do in order to make the App work with my remote DB? I am using C# (.net) and SQL server 2016.

Comment: If you really want to modernize what you're doing you may want to consider something like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-what-is-event-hubs. Not to be confused with SignalR event hubs. What did you end up doing btw?

Comment: Nothing worked, because the database structure could not suppoirt it. It needed a lot more effort to be refactored, so I decided to just build it from scratch to fit the new requirements. (of course keeping all the good stuff I had done before). Thanks!